# Kill Process in Java programmatically

Tags: java, multithreading, ant

I have a Swing application which get inputs through the text boxes and when Start button is Hit/clicked, we start a Ant script - programmatically (org.apache.tools.ant.Project, org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper) (ant file properties come from input text boxes). This Ant script will start checking out code from CVS.

Now, I want to stop this Ant script execution when user hits Stop button.

Problem:
As soon as user fills in text boxes and hits Start, I start the Ant script execution. So, the control moves from that Applet or Input page to back end java code. So I am not able to access "Stop" button in main applet.

Comment: I agree with John, you probably want to use some kind of threads.  I'd add "Ant" and "MultiThreading" tags if I were you.

Comment: Since you are not asking for killing an external process [nor current process], I edited the tags to reflect the problem you have.

Answer (score 3):

I can't be sure, but it sounds like what you want to do is use threads to execute the backend Java code, then tell that thread to terminate if the user hits stop.

Comment: Ant can run multiple threads itself. So killing original one might not actually help. But I am not sure.

Comment: I apologize, but I was under the impression that your GUI was freezing up due to the code executing Ant waiting on Ant to exit. If that was the case, you'd need to execute Ant in a separate thread.

Comment: Nothing to apologize for. Just discussing the idea. Actually, if `ant` is ran as part of the same process, that would probably work fine.

Comment: yes - just run the code in different thread and communicate the decision to stop to that thread when user hits stop and let the thread exit gracefully [say by calling some kind of cancel on ant if available].

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Kill 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe","fake.xml");
        p.directory(new File("c:/temp/"));

        System.out.println("Starting ...");
        Process x = p.start();
        System.out.println("Started ...");
        System.out.println("Sleeping ...");
        Thread.sleep(3000);     
        System.out.println("Woke up ...");
        System.out.println("Destroying...");

        x.destroy();
        x.waitFor(); // If you don't wait for it then the application will be terminated as soon as it is started

        System.out.println("Return value = " + x.exitValue());
        System.out.println("Over ...");
    }
}
```

One way is to use `x.waitFor();` method and keep waiting for either user action to kill the ant process or it may finishes by its own. Anyhow you will need the `x.destroy();` and check for the success and failure using the `x.exitValue()`. But using this in a worker thread makes more sense as the UI will remain responsive.

Comment: He will probably have to interrupt `waitFor` somehow when user hits stop button.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes. When using worker thread model he has to wait for either user action or the completion of the process i.e. Exactly what you said. But even terminating the process in the worker thread, the user may `waitFor(x millisecs)` after calling `destroy` on it.